# Injecting Doctrine into Tests - Symfony 4.1

Tags: php, symfony, testing

In Symfony 3.4 I was using this method to get doctrine entities in a test class:

**Test class (snippet):**

```
    $kernel = self::bootKernel();

    $em = $kernel->getContainer()
        ->get('doctrine')
        ->getManager();
```

This is deprecated.

I am attempting to inject the entity manager into my tests like this:

**services.yml**

```
Tests\AppBundle\NewUserTest:
    public: true
    autowire: true
    calls:
        - [ setEntityManager, ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']]
```

**Test class** (snippet, namespace = "Tests\AppBundle"):

```
/**
* @param EntityManager $em
*/

public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em)
{
    self::$em = $em;
}
```

I can't inject using constructor injection (as WebTestCases require a bunch of constructor params which I can't access)

Could someone help me out with this? I've been searching all over the place for this with no solution. There are some similar questions but not in a test environment.

Thanks :)

Comment: Tests are not services so I doubt your second approach is going to work.  What sort of depreciation notices are you getting?  The [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/doctrine.html) seem to indicate that the first approach is still valid.  Usually the docs will have a warning if something is going away.

Comment: @Cerad In Symfony 3.4 I was getting this: "58x: Passing "false" as the second argument to Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::getBundle() is deprecated as of 3.4 and will be removed in 4.0.
"

Comment: I assume you upgraded from a previous Symfony version?  The notice sort of implies that you still have a third party bundle somewhere that is not quite 3.4 ready.  Or maybe you have an older version of phpunit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create client for it. Client has all services, you need.

```
namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class WebTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $client;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
    }

    public function getLoggedInClient()
    {
        $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');
    }

}
```